# Reading CSV from Django model, No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, csv

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'static/data/cleanHeart.csv
```

I receive this error when attempting to access my csv file in my `models.py` file within a model named **Patient** and a method named **perform_prediction**.  My intent is to, with the use of some attributes available within **Patient**, to generate a prediction with the help of the data.

```py
import pandas as pd

def perform_prediction(self):
    main_df = pd.read_csv('static/data/cleanHeart.csv')
    regu = linReg.fit(main_df[['Age','Sex', 'ChestPainType', 'RestingBP', 'Cholesterol', 'FastingBS', 'RestingECG', 'MaxHR', 'ExerciseAngina', 'Oldpeak', 'ST_Slope']],main_df['HeartDisease'])
    tester = regu.predict([[65,0,3,140,306,1,0,87,1,1.5,0]])
    return tester
```

To ensure my relative path is correct, I created an **acceptablepath.py** in the exact same location with the method code, and was successfully able to access **cleanHeart.csv**.

I am calling this function from a template.  To ensure that was not the issue, I created a simple **ping_me** method which has no problems returning to the template.

```
def ping_me(self):
    return 'ping!'
```

Is this issue related to the settings.py in anyway?  I even placed the **cleanHeart.csv** in the same directory with **models.py** and I still am unable to access it.

There are no pending migrations.

Comment: Can you please post what your `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT` is set to in *settings.py*.

Comment: "I created an acceptablepath.py in the exact same location with the method code, and was successfully able to access cleanHeart.csv.": how do you mean? Do you mean you ran `acceptablepath.py` as a script in that directory? Or in another way (what way)?

Answer (score 1):

Relative paths such as `'static/data/cleanHeart.csv'` are relative to your process's working directory, which may or may not be where `manage.py` is. (A stray `os.chdir()` call anywhere in your project will also trash that assumption.)

If your code is in, say, `myapp/predictions.py`, then put `cleanHeart.csv` next to that file, i.e. `myapp/cleanHeart.csv`, and change things to

```
import pandas as pd
import os

csv_filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'cleanHeart.csv')

def perform_prediction():
    main_df = pd.read_csv(csv_filename)
    # ... etc...
```

to form the path to the data file based on the module's filename.